# Interchanging sums with inner sum in terms of outer sum variable

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, summation

I've got a double sum of the form

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left( \sum_{i=0}^k a_{i,k}  \right)    $$

and I'm trying to work out how you interchange these two sums. I remember seeing a formula for this in one of my courses, but I can't remember it (nor can I find my notes). As far as I remember, it comes out as two infinite sums.

I know when the inner sum isn't in terms of $k$, you can apply Fubini-Tonelli if the inner summands are all non-negative, but here that obviously doesn't make much sense. I tried to draw a grid with the entries and count them in a different order, but I keep getting the sum indexed by $i$ on the inside so I'm a little lost.

So, if anyone could prod me in the right direction, that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good way to remember is to write:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_{i,k} \chi(i \le k), $$
where $\chi$ represents the indicator function. Then you simply interchange the summation:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left( \sum_{i=0}^k a_{i,k}  \right) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{i,k} \chi(i \le k) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \sum_{k=i}^\infty a_{i,k}.$$
Obviously, you should be concerned with when you can apply Fubini.

Comment: Thank you! That's a great way of remembering how to do this

Answer (score 2):

> A slightly different notation:
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{i=0}^k a_{i,k}\right)=\sum_{\color{blue}{0\leq i\leq k<\infty}}a_{i,k}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=i}^\infty a_{i,k}\right)
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly switching the sums, you can use an intermediate step with only one sum, for example:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{i}f\left(\left(i,j\right)\right)\\
= \sum_{t\in\left\{ \left(i,j\right)\mid j\le i\le \infty\right\} }f\left(t\right)\\
= \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=j}^{\infty}f\left(\left(i,j\right)\right)$$

This has the advantage that it works with pretty much arbitrary amounts of nested summations and it's also easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write the terms as

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{i=0}^k a_{i,k} &= \color{blue}{a_{0,0}}\\   
&\ + \color{blue}{a_{0,1}} + \color{green}{a_{1,1}}\\  
&\ + \color{blue}{a_{0,2}} + \color{green}{a_{1,2}} + \color{red}{a_{2,2}}\\
&\ + \dots\\  
\end{align}

and this suggests reordering in a form
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{i=0}^k a_{i,k} &= (\color{blue}{a_{0,0}}+ \color{blue}{a_{0,1}} + \color{blue}{a_{0,2}}+\dots) \\   
&\ + (\color{green}{a_{1,1}} + \color{green}{a_{1,2}} + \color{green}{a_{1,3}} + \dots)\\  
&\ + (\color{red}{a_{2,2}} + \color{red}{a_{2,3}} + \color{red}{a_{2,4}} + \dots)\\  
&\ + \dots\\  
&=  \sum_{i=0}^\infty \sum_{k=i}^\infty a_{i,k}
\end{align}